# At a lost on real basic value from one method to another

Tags: java

I'm really struggling with some basic stuff here, my userInput method basically gets an array containing 3 values, all I want to do is push that value into the convert string method. I cannot for the life of me get it to work, please help and I apologise for my stupidity

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

    userInput();
    convertString();
}

private static String[] userInput(String[] results) {
    Scanner myUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int  numberOfEntries = 0;
    //Boolean isValidInput = true;
    String[] inPutList = new String[3];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a letter of the alphabet");
        inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
        while (!inPutList[i].matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a letter of the alphabet ony");
            inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
        }
    }
     System.out.println("You have entered: "+ Arrays.toString(inPutList));

    return inPutList;
}

private static void convertString(String[] list) {
    String[] storedInput = userInput(inPutList);
    System.out.println(storedInput);
}
```

}

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: think my questions is pretty clear, why is inPutList not available for the convertString, I have returned it from userInput method

Comment: `userInput` actually returns an array of strings, however you don´t do anything with that array. You should use that array and provide it to `convertString`, e.g. convertString(userInput())`.

Comment: Your code won't even compile since parameters are missing from the calls to userInput() and convertString() in main().

Comment: I was trying to be to clever and I was focused on why I couldn't pass the array from one method to another, I was then going to move to the main. I simplified it by moving the first method to be called from the second method and then stored the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method calls do not match with the arguments of the method. You should do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertString();
    }

    private static String[] userInput() {
        Scanner myUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inPutList = new String[3];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a letter of the alphabet: ");
            inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
            while (!inPutList[i].matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a letter of the alphabet ony: ");
                inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You have entered: " + Arrays.toString(inPutList));
        return inPutList;
    }

    private static void convertString() {
        String[] storedInput = userInput();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(storedInput));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please enter a letter of the alphabet: A
Please enter a letter of the alphabet: B
Please enter a letter of the alphabet: C
You have entered: [A, B, C]
[A, B, C]
```

As you see, you just need to call `convertString` from `main` because `convertString` will in turn call `userInput`. Moreover, I have removed the arguments from the signature of the methods to match with their calls.

**Alternatively**, you also do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertString(userInput());
    }

    private static String[] userInput() {
        Scanner myUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inPutList = new String[3];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a letter of the alphabet: ");
            inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
            while (!inPutList[i].matches("[A-Za-z]+")) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a letter of the alphabet ony: ");
                inPutList[i] = myUserInput.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You have entered: " + Arrays.toString(inPutList));
        return inPutList;
    }

    private static void convertString(String[] list) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

The key is that the method call should match with its signature.

Comment: Nail on the head for me, I simplified it down and it worked. I was trying to run before I could walk

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that convertString expects an argument and you aren't providing one.

```
    String[] arr = .. some values.
    convertString(arr);
```

Is how you call it.

In your case, do this since user input returns an array.

```
    String[] values = userInput();
    convertString(values);
```

Change your `convertString` method to this. And then make the changes in main that I suggested earlier.

```
private static void convertString(String[] storedInput) {
    System.out.println(storedInput);
}
```

If you want to do it by getting user inputs from converString then do it this way.

```
main(String[] args) {
   convertString(); // no arguments needed here and none in the method.
}
```

And the method.

```
    private static void convertString() {
        String[] storedItems = userInput();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(storedItems);
    }
```

Comment: I don't really understand, I want to be able to use inPutList from the userInput method in my convertString method. No matter what I do it won't work and now my main is messed up. It makes zero sense to me to be honest.

Comment: @PaulBFitzsimons see my last two highlighted suggestions.  I think that is what you originally wanted to do.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience, I ended up simplifying my main and then updating the second method to call the first instead of calling both from the main.